# How to set dynamic variable name in Angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs

This is my controller code :

```
var selectableFields = ["customerName", "customerAddress"];

angular.forEach(selectableFields, function(field, key) {
var value = $.jStorage.get(field); //using jStore to get the values
$scope.field=value;

});
```

The objective is to be able to access {{customerName}} and {{customerAddress}} in the view.
Can anyone please tell me what is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `$scope[field] = value;` instead.

With `$scope.field`, you're creating a new attribute named `field`.

Comment: +1, I would also recommend to the OP that he/she not add 'dynamic variables' directly to the scope object. Instead, if it is a form (for example), have it `$scope.form[field] = value;`.

Comment: I am facing same issue but not able to solve, can you help me?

Comment: Hi @sp00m, in my angularjs app I have created a config file where I am defining all constants. Its a CRUD functionality code with API's

In my AngularJs application. I have an identifier for ex. response.userid  now for different instance it could be response.productid

And I want to create a constant something like (var id = 'productid'; ) in my config file where I can change it at top and it will check for relevant variable accordingly.

for example if(response.id) then do this; // here
What I should be doing in this case?

Answer (score 1):

```
   var pages=["kedi","köpek","tavşan","ayi"]

pages.map(page =>{
        $rootScope["adChangeUrl"+page]="dene.com"
        $rootScope["imgSrc"+page]="images/deneme.png"
        $rootScope["imgAdTitle"+page]="deneme.com"
        $rootScope["imgAdAlt"+page]="https://deneme.com/"
    }
    )
//console.log Output

adChangeUrlayi: "dene.com"
adChangeUrlkedi: "dene.com"
adChangeUrlköpek: "dene.com"
adChangeUrltavşan: "dene.com"
imgAdAltayi: "https://deneme1.com/"
imgAdAltkedi: "https://deneme1.com/"
imgAdAltköpek: "https://deneme1.com/"
imgAdAlttavşan: "https://deneme1.com/"
imgAdTitleayi: "deneme.com"
imgAdTitlekedi: "deneme.com"
imgAdTitleköpek: "deneme.com"
imgAdTitletavşan: "deneme.com"
imgSrcayi: "images/deneme.png"
imgSrckedi: "images/deneme.png"
imgSrcköpek: "images/deneme.png"
imgSrctavşan: "images/deneme.png"
```